# Using anonymous function in loop versus named function

Tags: javascript

I execute function (which has callback) in loop. I consider about using anonymous function as callback or use named function. Look at the example code below:

**Anonymous function**

```
for(let i=0;i<50;i++){
example_func(param1,param2,()=>{

});
}
```

**Named function**

```
for(let i=0;i<50;i++){
example_func(param1,param2,callback);
}

function callback(){
    
}
```

Which way is better? Will I have better performance with named function, whether it doesn't matter?

Answer (score 2):

Having a named function which is declared *outside* of the loop may have very slightly better performance, because it only needs to be created once. In contrast, putting an anonymous (or named) function inside each iteration of the loop will cause the function to be created every time the loop runs.

But, on modern computers and on modern JS environments, unless the loop is running an unreasonably huge number of iterations, any effect will be completely insignificant. Better to write clean and readable code (in whichever style you prefer).

If, later, you find that some operation isn't running as fast as you think it should, feel free to debug the code and track down what exactly is causing the bottleneck - but this section will almost certainly not be it.